# Creating a regular expression in django

Tags: python, django

New to Django, so I'm unsure how to achieve the following...

I have this regular expression

```
"@£$¥èéùìòÇ\fØø\nÅåΔ_ΦΓΛΩΠΨΣΘΞÆæßÉ !\"#¤%&'()*+,-./[0-9]:;<=>\?¡[A-Z]ÄÖÑÜ§¿[a-z]äöñüà\^\{\}\[~\]\|€"
```

I have this function:

```
def validate_GSM_characters(value):
    """ Raise a ValidationError if the value contains any values not within
        the GSM character set.
    """
    msg = u"Invalid characters."

    raise ValidationError(msg)
```

At the moment it does nothing, but I need to know how in Django/Python I can create a regex function that allows me to check a value. I did a Google search and can only find articles relating to model validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the expression with the `re` module:

```
import re

yourrule = re.compile(r"@£$¥èéùìòÇ\fØø\nÅåΔ_ΦΓΛΩΠΨΣΘΞÆæßÉ !\"#¤%&'()*+,-./[0-9]:;<=>\?¡[A-Z]ÄÖÑÜ§¿[a-z]äöñüà\^\{\}\[~\]\|€")

def validate_GSM_characters(value):
    """ Raise a ValidationError if the value contains any values not within
        the GSM character set.
    """
    if not yourrule.search(value):
        msg = u"Invalid characters."

        raise ValidationError(msg)
```

You could also just use a [`RegexValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/validators/#regexvalidator); simply pass it your expression and your message, then use that instead of the above function.